# Run a file 24x7 on server using PORT

Tags: php, sockets, tcp, port, serversocket

I am stuck with this problem. I am using a server ( I have full excess rights and can do anything ). On this, I want to run a file which will connect to a port and receive data from devices. These devices will send data using TCP.

Server file should run continuously, 24x7, without any break. But it is not happening. To understand deeper I am pasting the code.

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die("Could not create socket\n");
$result = socket_listen($socket) or die("Could not set up socket listener\n");
while(true) {
    if ($spawn = socket_accept($socket)) {

        if ($input = socket_read($spawn, 1024)) {
            // MY REST OF THE CODE HERE
        }

        socket_close($spawn);
        unset($spawn);
    }
}
```

In line number 5, server will accept the connection and next loop will be executed. It goes well if devices are sending data continuously. It will wait for device and once receive data, it will proceed further. But after some hours, server file stops responding. Port is consumed but server does not work on data. I made a client file to test whether port is working or not. Client file successfully connected with server.

What should I do to run this file continuously 24x7 without error.
One more thing I want to ask is, what if for some time device stops sending data ? Will it affect line 5 ? and this will lead to file hang ?

Comment: You could make it run via `inetd` instead. Typcially a plain socket server script also ought to spawns suprocesses for availability (daemonize) and more implicit garbage collection. Look into PEAR::Net_Server

Comment: Thanks mario for replying. Please explain that what is the problem with my code. I will definitely search for `inetd` but as a programer I must know that what is the actual problem.